# handle the event of finished editing of the cell value (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

Hi in my EXCEL workbook I am using vba. How can I handle the event of loss of focus of the cell or finished editing its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event. For example in the code below we are checking if any changes have been made in cell `A1`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note even if you press <kbd>F2</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the above event will fire. If you need to run the code only if there is an actual change in the cell then you will have to take help of a `Public` variable which will store the previous value of the cell.

The `Worksheet_Change` event goes in the sheet code area. Please see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please, can you send me a source code. I put your example in my sheet , this event does not occur

Comment: `1` Which sheet did you put it in? `2` Are macros enabled? `3` Are events enabled?

Comment: I put it in one of my sheet. Macros is enabled. How can I check if event enabled?

Comment: In the `Immediate Window`, type this `Application.EnableEvents = True` and press enter and it will enable the events. To access the `Immediate Window`, press `Ctrl G` in your VBA Editor.

Answer (score 1):

See this Link: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s194/event-handling-vba.htm

There are five different short, helpful articles on events, how to use them, and which events are available to you. This article was helpful to me also.